# Inserting quotes around all value in whole Oracle Table

Tags: oracle

I have table as Table1  (this table has various data types)

```
ID    Name    Price    Date
123   James   0.9832   04/01/2015
345   Jacob   0.23412  05/01/2015
```

I want to create table Table2 having all data types as char and single quotes around it in the table

Required: Table2

```
ID       Name       Price       Date
'123'   'James'   '0.9832'   '04/01/2015'
'345'   'Jacob'   '0.23412'  '05/01/2015'
```

so, when I extract data as .txt file it should be look like

```
ID,Name,Price,Date  
'123','James','0.9832','04/01/2015'  
'345','Jacob','0.23412','05/01/2015'
```

Comment: why not just create your output file with the required format using a `select` statement? (Keeping 2 tables of same data seems non-optimal). Good luck.

Comment: I cannt because... we have almost 10million records and if I do select and save as txt file memory issue come. Its good to change in the table and Unload whole table as .txt file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way to is create a view using this syntax

```
CREATE VIEW TEXT_EXPORT as
SELECT ''''||ID||'''' AS "ID",''''||Name||''''AS "NAME",''''||Price||''''AS "PRICE",''''||Date||'''' AS "DATE"
FROM TABLE1;
```

I agree there are better ways to export text than this. And using Oracle keywords as column names will hurt.

Comment: @Qasim0787 : That's what I'm talking about! ;-) Good luck to all.